# There are $73$ prizes in a raffle with $730$ tickets available

Tags: statistics

There are $73$ prizes in a raffle with $730$ tickets available.  Does one ticket have a $10\%$ chance of winning and $10$ tickets have a $100\%$ chance of winning? Is that true?

Comment: Did you mean to ask if having one ticket gives you a $10\%$ chance of winning and having ten tickets gives you a $100\%$ chance of winning?

Comment: And 146 tickets have a 200% chance of winning?

Comment: $100\%$ chance of winning means, in this case, that you're _guaranteed_ to win. That doesn't happen until you buy $658$ tickets.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completion purposes.

Assume that there are $pr$ prizes, $N$ tickets in the raffle box and we buy $t$ tickets. Then, the probability to win *at least* one of the prizes is:
$$p = 1 - \dfrac{\dbinom{N-pr}{t}}{\dbinom{N}{t}}$$
In our case we have: $pr = 73, N = 730, t = 10$, thus:
$$ p = 1 - \dfrac{\dbinom{730 - 73}{10}}{\dbinom{730}{10}}\approx 0.653=65.3\%$$

---

As @Arthur said, if we set $t = 658$, then $p = 1$.

Comment: Nice. Completion and clarification are in such short supply.

Comment: @BruceET Thank you very much.